# NSLog giving error when trying to print a single unformatted integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

Hi this is third day of mine using Objective-C today I was writing few simple programs and i ecncountered the following warning

main.m:19:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     NSLog(res);

which finally resulted in the **Segmentation fault**.. Here is my program..

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SomeClass: NSObject
{
    int x;
}
@property int x;
@end

@implementation SomeClass

@synthesize x;
@end

int main(){ 
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
SomeClass * obj = [[SomeClass alloc]init];
obj.x =20;
int res = obj.x;
NSLog(res); //error
/* But the error was not seen when I replaced the above statement with 
 NSLog(@"The value is : %d",res);
 */
[pool drain];
return 0;
}
```

The error message that I got was :

```
Compiling the source code....
$gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -L/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lgnustep-base main.m -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lreadline 2>&1
main.m: In function 'main':
main.m:19:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
     NSLog(res);
     ^
In file included from /usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/Foundation/NSObject.h:30:0,
                 from /usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/Foundation/FoundationErrors.h:29,
                 from /usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/Foundation/Foundation.h:33,
                 from main.m:1:
/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h:146:16: note: expected 'struct NSString *' but argument is of type 'int'
 GS_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
                ^

Executing the program....
$demo 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Please help by making me understand why NSLog behaves like this ? Where did I go wrong?
Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant declare the `NSLog` like that see the tutorial for `NSLog` its may be useful for you.

Objective-C has a number of built-in data types:

int – integer constant

float – real numbers with fractional component

double – double precision floating point number

char – a single character

short – short integer (2 bytes)

long – double short

long long – double long

BOOL – boolean

The utility function `NSLog()` can be used to print to the debug console in Xcode.  `NSLog()` uses the `NSString` formatting services.  The easiest way to create a `NSString` is to use the `@”"` notation.  Inside a format string a `%` is a placeholder for a value.  The character after the `%` determines the value expected, be it an int or a float and so on.  If we declare an integer “`int i = 5`″ and want to print the value of i with `NSLog()` we can do it with `NSLog(@”The value of i is %d”,  i);`

You can use `%d` to print the value of an int, `%f` for a float and double, `%c` for a char.  For a full listing of all format specifiers supported by NSString formatting methods read through the documentation.

For More Reference [Click Here](http://programmingios.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/objective-c-basic-data-types-and-nslog/)

keep learning..:)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the NSLog like this, You need to specify the control string and use like:

```
NSLog(@"%d",res);
```

The format should be specified for `NSLog()`, please check the [NSLog and NSLogv reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLogv)  for more information

> ### NSLog
>
> Logs an error message to the Apple System Log facility.
>
> `void NSLog (    NSString *format,    ... );`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Simply calls NSLogv, passing it a variable number of arguments.
>   Availability
>
> ---
>
> ### NSLogv
>
> Logs an error message to the Apple System Log facility.
>
> `void NSLogv (    NSString *format,    va_list args );`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Logs an error message to the Apple System Log facility (see man 3
>   asl). If the STDERR_FILENO file descriptor has been redirected away
>   from the default or is going to a tty, it will also be written there.
>   If you want to direct output elsewhere, you need to use a custom
>   logging facility.
>
> The message consists of a timestamp and the process ID prefixed to the
>   string you pass in. You compose this string with a format string,
>   format, and one or more arguments to be inserted into the string. The
>   format specification allowed by these functions is that which is
>   understood by NSString’s formatting capabilities (which is not
>   necessarily the set of format escapes and flags understood by printf).
>   The supported format specifiers are described in “String Format
>   Specifiers”. A final hard return is added to the error message if one
>   is not present in the format.
>
> In general, you should use the NSLog function instead of calling this
>   function directly. If you do use this function directly, you must have
>   prepared the variable argument list in the args argument by calling
>   the standard C macro va_start. Upon completion, you must similarly
>   call the standard C macro va_end for this list.
>
> Output from NSLogv is serialized, in that only one thread in a process
>   can be doing the writing/logging described above at a time. All
>   attempts at writing/logging a message complete before the next thread
>   can begin its attempts.
>
> The effects of NSLogv are not serialized with subsystems other than
>   those discussed above (such as the standard I/O package) and do not
>   produce side effects on those subsystems (such as causing buffered
>   output to be flushed, which may be undesirable). Availability

Answer (score 0):

The 1st argument to NSLog is an `NSString` that should be a string with 0 or more format specifiers.

Use:

```
NSLog(@"res = %d", res);
```

or just:

```
NSLog(@"%d", res);
```

Have a look at the reference docs for `NSLog` for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the compiler that what kind of data type you want to print in Log,

```
    NSLog(@"%d",res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not never use `NSLog(variable)` directly. Instead, use `NSLog(@"%d", variable)` for integers or `NSLog(@"%@", object)` for objects.